# Node.js Express - Conditional Rendering of Template

Tags: node.js, express, password-less

I am using Express and Passwordless module to setup passwordless authentication. Everything works, gte, but i am stuck at one issue.

As a part of the delivery method, I am using an external api to send the sms to the user. If the sms is sent correctly, everything works fine. However, if the sms fails to send, there is still no error, but the response from the api call tells me that the sms wa a failure. In case of failure, the api response looks like this:

{ warnings: [ { message: 'Message sending has failed', numbers: '91545454' } ],  errors: [ { code: 51, message: 'No valid numbers specified' } ],
  status: 'failure' }

Now, in my node/express app, if the api response has status = failure, I would like to send them to a different page where I will tell users that the sms failed.

My code looks like this:

```
passwordless.addDelivery(
    function(tokenToSend, uidToSend, recipient, callback) {

    var smscall = 'MY API CALL URL;
    needle.get(smscall, function(error, response) {
      if(error) {
          console.log(error);
      }
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(response.body);
      }
      if(response.body.status == 'failure') {
        console.log('Failed');
        THIS IS WHERE I WOULD LIKE TO REDIRECT USER TO A DIFFERENT TEMPLATE OR RENDER A MESSAGE.
      }
      callback(error);
    });
});
```

The requestToken code looks like below:

```
router.post('/', passwordless.requestToken(function(user, delivery, callback) {
    callback(null, user);
    }, { failureRedirect: '/error' }),
    function (req, res) {
        res.render('verify', { uid: req.passwordless.uidToAuth });
    }
);
```

Comment: please post the code with `requestToken`.

Comment: I've added the requestToken code also.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call a callback with error in your last condition block.

```
if(response.body.status === 'failure') {
     console.log('Failed');
     return callback(new Error(response.body.status));
}
```

Comment: I did this and it works also. However, this is creating an error and the error handler page will be shown. Instead, I would like to render a completely different page. How do I do that?

Comment: You cannot do it. You may check only  error message in your route and render needed template for specific error.

Comment: I have this errorhandler code in my app... app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: err
    });
}); is it possible y customzie this to show different template for different errors?

Answer (score 0):

Just call res.render where you check for the failed sms status :

passwordless.addDelivery(
    function(tokenToSend, uidToSend, recipient, callback) {

```
var smscall = 'MY API CALL URL;
needle.get(smscall, function(error, response) {
  if(error) {
      console.log(error);
  }
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(response.body);
  }
  if(response.body.status == 'failure') {
    console.log('Failed');
    return res.render('smsFailPage');
  }
  callback(error);
});
```

});

Comment: res.render('smsFailpage') give the error res.render is not a function. I even tried response.render but get the same error. Not sure how to handle it. Really appreciate any help.